# jqgrid navgrid add button after search button and custom buttons

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

I have add and search buttons from nav grid.
and export csv,delete , refresh and toolbar search buttons from navButtonAdd.

I want to change the order of buttons like this:-
Toolbar search, navgrid search,refresh ,export,add ,delete.

Issue is with navgrid buttons ,how can I bring search button after toolbar search and add button at the end.
I have used position:first with navAddButtons which gives me the sequence :-

toolbar search,refresh , export, add ,search, delete

I want to bring this search after toolbar search

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `insertAfter`, `insertBefore`, `after`, `before`, `append`, `appendTo`, `prepend` or `prependTo` to move the bottons on another place in the navigator bar.

For example if you add new button to the navigator bar, you can assign unique `id` attribute to it:

```js
$grid.jqGrid("navGrid", "#pager", ...);
$grid.jqGrid("navButtonAdd", "#pager", {
    id: "myButton",
    onClickButton: function () {
        ...
    },
    ...
});

var $nav = $("#pager").find(".navtable");
$("#search_" + $grid[0].id).prependTo($nav);
$("#myRefresh").prependTo($nav);
$("#del_" + $grid[0].id).appendTo($nav);
```

The above code creates standard navigator bar, add `#myButton` button at the end of navigator bar. Then one move the button Search button and the custom button at the beginning of the navigator bar and move Delete button at the end of navigator bar.

I should remark that one could reduce the code in some cases by usage `position: "first"` option of `navButtonAdd`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Oleg. I used insertAfter like this :-     $("#searchGrid").insertAfter("#searchToolbarGrid");